# Crystal Reports and SQL Server 2008 datetimeoffset

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, datetimeoffset

SQL Server 2008 introduced new data type datetimeoffset which stores local time and offset between local time and UTC. But when a table containing datetimeoffset column is added to Crystal Reports 2008, the datetimeoffset column is exposed as string in CR Field Explorer rather than DateTime. Is there a way to manipulate datetimeoffset to get the date, time and offset values in CR 2008 other than string conversion? Is there a DateTimeOffset data type in CR 2010?

Sample of datetimeoffset string as displayed in CR 2008:

2009-08-14 16:37:32.0000000 +07:00

Answer (score 2):

This is the kind of impedance that can easily be countered with a view.

You could create a view representation of that table (or all tables that have the datetime offsets) and use SQL Server's native functions to convert the problematic date time fields into a result set that Crystal Reports can consume without having to resort to string parsing.

If you don't want to bother with a view you can also just write a query that converts from datetimeoffset to a datetime [thusly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953903/how-can-i-convert-a-sql-server-2008-datetimeoffset-to-a-datetime).

Comment: Views and stored procedures would work of course, but its not always feasible for us. Often, the reports use direct table linking - CR just needs to handle this new data type properly.  
I was just wondering if anyone else came across this issue and how did they handle it? Also, if CR 2010 can handle the datatimeoffset properly.