# TSQL Date conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime-conversion

I have a SQL table with datetime2 objects, and they are stored in UTC TIME

for example

```
UTC_TIME = 2017-10-20T13:16:14.6950000
```

I have successfully converted this timestamp to local time using

```
SELECT UTC_TIME AT TIME ZONE 'W. Europe Standard Time' AS LOCAL_TIME
```

The output of the above is

> 2017-10-20T13:16:14.6950000+02:00

This is correct, but the output I want is

> 2017-10-20T15:16:14.6950000

The offset should be added to my timestamp.

Is there an easy way to do this ?

Example :
An event was logged on UTC time 2017-10-20T13:16:14.6950000
I'm in Western Europe, and for the moment there is an offset of 2 hours. So the actual local time is 2017-10-20T15:16:14.6950000

I would like to convert the UTC time (13:16), so that the result is 15:16

The query is executed on a server that runs in UTC timezone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a Sql Server 2008 DateTimeOffset to a DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953903/how-can-i-convert-a-sql-server-2008-datetimeoffset-to-a-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

As AT TIME ZONE returns a DateTimeOffset you can use `CONVERT` with option 1.

```
DECLARE @UTC_TIME DATETIME2(7) = '2017-10-20T13:16:14.6950000'

SELECT CONVERT(datetime2, (@UTC_TIME AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time'), 1) AS OrderDate_TimeZonePST
```

See also [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)

Comment: This does not work :: 

DECLARE UTC_TIME DATETIME2(7) = '2017-10-20T13:16:14.6950000'

SELECT 
UTC_TIME AS T0, 
UTC_TIME AT TIME ZONE 'W. Europe Standard Time' AS T1,
CONVERT(datetime2, (UTC_TIME AT TIME ZONE 'W. Europe Standard Time'), 1) AS T2   

answer I get back is 
T0 : 2017-10-20T13:16:14.6950000, 
T1 : 2017-10-20T13:16:14.6950000+02:00, 
T2 : 2017-10-20T11:16:14.6950000,  

but the expexted value is 2017-10-20T15:16:14.6950000 (as I would read on a local clock)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [sysdatetimeoffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysdatetimeoffset-transact-sql)

```
declare @UTC_Time datetime2 = '2017-10-20T13:16:14.6950000'

Select dateadd(minute, datepart(TZoffset, sysdatetimeoffset()), @UTC_Time)
```

Comment: This does not work either, as the SQL server is running in the cloud, in UTC timezone ...

Answer (score 0):

This seems the way to do it :

```
    DECLARE @UTC_TIME DATETIME2(7) = '2017-10-20T13:16:14.6950000'

    SELECT 
    @UTC_TIME AS T0, 
    @UTC_TIME AT TIME ZONE 'W. Europe Standard Time' AS T1,
    dateadd(minute,DATEdiff(minute,@UTC_TIME AT TIME ZONE 'W. Europe Standard Time',@UTC_TIME ),@UTC_TIME) as T2
```

The result is
T0 : 2017-10-20T13:16:14.6950000

T1 : 2017-10-20T13:16:14.6950000+02:00

T2 : 2017-10-20T15:16:14.6950000

T2 is what we would see on the local clock for an event happening at UTC time T0