# How to convert DateTimeOffeset to DateTime in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, data-conversion

How to convert `DateTimeOffset` to `DateTime`?

I have tried using:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, 2018-03-02 12:00:00.0000000 -07:00, 120)
```

but the result is:

```
"2018-03-02 12:00:00 -07:00"
```

Ex: `"2018-03-02 12:00:00.0000000 -07:00"` to `"2018-03-02 12:00:00"`

Comment: Does this satisfy your needs?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953903/how-can-i-convert-a-sql-server-2008-datetimeoffset-to-a-datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [site I linked to above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953903/how-can-i-convert-a-sql-server-2008-datetimeoffset-to-a-datetime), and in my own testing, this works:

select select CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), CONVERT(DATETIME, SWITCHOFFSET('2018-03-02 12:00:00.0000000 -07:00', DATEPART(tz, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))),120)

That should do it!

Comment: Thanks Phil.It worked but I can't get rid of milliseconds the result is "2018-03-02 12:00:00.000" instead of "2018-03-02 12:00:00"

Comment: @K.Tom - How about now?

Answer (score 0):

Please use below conversion

```
declare @createdate datetimeoffset
set @createdate = '2018-03-02 12:00:00.0000000 -07:00'
select convert(datetimeoffset,CONVERT(datetime2, @createdate , 1))
```

Comment: Did you try that before posting it? It's not even close to what he's after.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.